# Cleaning up line art with choppy edges

Tags: gimp, images, raster

So, a while back I created this icon from a game, but looking back on it behind a white background instead of an alpha-channel its edges are super choppy in some places while it's smooth in others, which is possibly due to the method I used to select certain regions before bucket-filling it. I was using GIMP and I was wondering if there is *any* possible way to easily fix this (ie make all edges even instead of choppy). Maybe some rendering filters or selection methods that I don't know about? I've googled and youtubed but with no avail.

My image:

[image: http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/177/7/c/seal_of_mar_by_jacedc-d695fa3.png]

(As you can see, the inner crescent-shaped things are choppy as well as the exterior of the circle on the left and right is choppy)

Comment: You've tagged is as raster and state you used Gimp. Raster apps are always going to result in some pixels at the edges of arcs. If you use a vector application, you can get cleaner lines.

Comment: @Scott Well I was the one that tagged it as raster (though it's clearly a raster image)

Comment: I used GIMP and somewhere along the lines (no pun intended) it ended up looking like a really choppy raster image. I was wondering if there's a quick solution to just round out all of the edges.

Comment: @BenBrocka - the question states Gimp.. so raster is a good tag. not sure why it was removed. Jacedc - are you asking how in Gimp??? As I've commented, a raster app isn't going to offer many more solutions. There is no "magic' button.

Comment: In order to avoid the "choppy" edges for future images you create this way: make sure that all your selections are feathered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say there's no quick and dirty fix for choppy lines, you just gotta recreate it using vectors. The following took me 3 minutes in Photoshop with Circles and Stroke effect:

[image: Logo Example]

I'm not going to do it all for you, but all you need is two more half circles and you've got a shape based logo, which should scale beautifully to any size. So that's 6 circles, two semi-circles and a stroke applied to some of them. In your case it's very simple to recreate, but a detailed logo would take a lot longer.

There are various ways to do this, though in your case I'd just knuckle down and spend a little while doing this, if you're proficient with any GD software that creates shapes, this shouldn't even take half an hour and if you aren't, now is a good time to learn a few reusable skills.

Also `Save for Web & Devices..`

Comment: Okay. Yeah I'm not really "proficient" in any GD software except GIMP which I guess doesn't do vectors. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Photoshop has vector tools but "doesn't do vectors" either in reality.

Comment: @Dominic Yes, **within Photoshop** and ONLY within Photoshop. True vector files can be scaled anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean "creates shapes"? It has rectangle and ellipse select (as well as free select and the "paths tool"), but other than that, no.

Comment: Note that Inkscape is suitable for this sort of thing and is GPL

Comment: photoshop has basic and somewhat advanced tools for vector especially latest version but illustrator is better. However for this, photoshop is more than enough.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the best answer to fix an issue with an open source tool is to recommend re-doing it using a licensed (and very expensive) tool.

Comment: @Liam if I recall correctly, you could rent Photoshop for roughly £10 a month until you no longer need it. I actually answered without seeing the gimp tag and there's no point removing it after the fact. The advice about the shapes is useful for all software anyway.

Answer (score 9):

#### Tracing

In case we can not easily recreate the original in a vector oriented application we may also trace the bitmap to a vector graphic.

Below example was done with **Inkscape** where I imported the bitmap to trace it with 2 color steps:

[image]

This will not preserve the exact circular geometry of the source (note the slightly wavy shapes above), as tracing was done with Bezier curves rather than circles or boxes. Because of that such traces will always have a much bigger file size than properly recreated vectors.

---

### Smoothing

Another possibility to reduce aliasing in a bitmap if we can not use a vector graphic replacement is to apply a soft blur to the image.

Below I used the GIMP plugin [GREYC's magic filter](http://gmic.eu/): *Enhancement - Smooth (mean-curvature)* with 8 iterations for smoothing the outlines while keeping the alpha channel:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Very nice! I'll take a look at inkscape. Thanks!

Comment: [This link](http://gmic.eu/) may be better for getting the current G'MIC plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really simple way to do this by using the fuzzy select tool to create a path. There is a short example on how to do it at [Fixing Jagged Image Edges with Gimp](http://jafty.com/blog/fixing-jagged-image-edges-with-gimp/).

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: I've replaced the link with a different one that isn't as detailed but does provide the steps needed.

Comment: Many thanks, I couldn't figure out which would be a good match for what was originally there.

Comment: Let me know how you get on - I can try to find a better option if that one doesn't work for you.

Comment: New link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

For smaller projects, simply using the *blur* tool can do wonders.  While this doesn't apply to this particular project, other people looking may find this solution expedient.