# clean up edges in lineart in gimp

Tags: gimp

I am working on this lineart as sort of a logo for my tshirt company. I was wondering how exactly to clean up the edges and smooth them out?i would just like it to look like a classic clean lineart that i could fill and color.[image: after stroke selection] It was originally a pencil drawing that was scanned and darkened using the stroke selection in gimp.[image: before stroke selection just scanned] This is my first experience creating my own lineart. I have colored and filled others multiple times

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19086/cleaning-up-line-art-with-choppy-edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Color-Select tool and select black
- `Select>To path`
- Add new layer
- `Select>From path`
- Bucket-fill

[image]

But IMHO you could have avoided the problem earlier. For instance, from your original:

- Threshold (around 180)
- `Filters>Generic>Erode`
- `Filters>Blur>Gaussian blur` (5px)
- Brightness/Contrast tool and increase contrast a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something I suggest to use tracing. If you can afford Illustrator, I recommend its Live Trace. With it you can trace your strokes. After tracing and expanding the result you can modify the strokes freely like they were  drawn in Illustrator. See the following screenshot of the tracing result:

[image]

Unfortunately Inkscape (=freeware) cannot trace line art as strokes. That makes it nearly useless at this job.

Comment: You can do this inkscape its just not very intuitive. Anyway you can use any number of other tracers for this. Didn't down vote but this MIGHT be why you got down voted.